# JQGrid, fill a select dropdown from MySQL db

Tags: java, mysql, jqgrid

I am trying to fill a select dropdown from a MySQL database on an edit form for a jQGrid. Here is my code so far:

```
$col = array();
$col["title"] = "Unpacked By";
$col["name"] = "operators_name";
$col["width"] = "30";
$col["editable"] = true; // this column is editable
$col["align"] = "center";
$col["edittype"] = "select"; // render as select
$col["editoptions"] = "dataUrl../TextilePrintingManager/Administrator/filename.php";
$col["cacheUrlData"] = TRUE;
$cols[] = $col;
```

Comment: You might want to edit your title to match the format of the other questions on Stack Overflow.  Also, please tell us what is going wrong with your existing code.

Comment: Yes, please make it clear what the question is.

Comment: in the edit options, i want to select from a field in mysql database.

Comment: the edit options is not selecting from the database

Comment: the select option is showing blank with no value to select

Comment: The string `"dataUrl../TextilePrintingManager/Administrator/filename.php"` looks suspectted. Do you want to set `dataUrl` property of `editoptions` to `"/TextilePrintingManager/Administrator/filename.php"`? I'm not PHP developer, but `$col["editoptions"] = "dataUrl../TextilePrintingManager/Administrator/filename.php";` looks wrong for me.